# Can I change an interview date, where the company have refused to be flexible with the date?

Tags: interviewing, manager

I had agreed to take my terminally ill Auntie abroad which was booked before I was given the interview date. I have explained this to my employer but they say they can't change the date for me.

Do I have any rights?

Comment: questions about rights require you specify the country. Also is this your employer or a potential employer?

Comment: An interview is a two way street.  They just failed.  Find another company.

Comment: This question is confusing. You are asking about interviewing, but then also discuss the company as if you already work for them. Please clarify: Are you going for an interview (perhaps for a transfer or promotion) within the company you already work for? Or is this an interview with a company you don't work for (yet)? Also, as @mhoran_psprep said, to discuss rights, you need to say where you are ... although you're then getting into legal territory, which is generally off topic here. For more about that, see http://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour and http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help.

Answer (score 6):

If you've already explained your situation to them, and they still can't or won't be flexible, then you're out of luck.  You don't really have any "rights" when it comes to interviewing, they can choose whether or not they want to be flexible, they don't "owe" you anything as you're not employed.  So no, you don't have any rights, and it's probably best to just forget this job, or find a way to have someone watch over your Aunt while you interview.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer is NO. But again if your potential employer is so inflexible for things like that, .i.e. healthcare needs of your loved ones, do you really want to work for an outfit like that. Ask that question to yourself.

As someone from outside the company, you have no rights whatsoever. Even after you are hired, yo do not have many rights other than discrimination cases against any protected class, but that is about it for the United States. Since you did not state where you are from, it might be different for you.

Comment: As an employee in the USA, if the ill relative were a son, daughter, or parent the Family Medical Leave Act would give some rights.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: How does the FMLA give rights to someone who is not yet employed by the company in question?

Comment: @GreenMatt I was responding to "Even after you are hired".

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Fair enough, although I don't think the FMLA guarantees the change of an internal interview to fit the time off you take under it.

Answer (score 1):

Apply all the normal throw clearings of "I'm not an attorney" and "this is not legal advice" ...

I can't imagine there's a jurisdiction in the world that can or should extend "rights" to a candidate as to when an interview is to be held. If they were really interested in you, or your skills were particularly hard to find, they would be more accommodating out of necessity.

Consider yourself lucky. Not many companies advertise that they are going to be inflexible right from the outset.