# Job interview cancelled due to family emergency

Tags: interviewing

Hiya just wanted some help regarding a rescheduled interview, spoke to the employer & had to cancel the agreed meeting, & emailed her too, but haven't heard anything as yet, it's been 3 day's, what shall I do next.......any response much appreciated xxxxx

Comment: You sounded like you are person who posted [THIS TOPIC](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/64589/can-i-change-an-interview-date-where-the-company-have-refused-to-be-flexible-wi). As everyone over there said, the company you cancelled the interview with, has no obligation towards you. But, on the flipside, be happy that you won't be working for such an inflexible organization.

Answer (score 2):

Why not call them on Monday morning to find out what is happening? You may have missed the boat. If so I would say to yourself that it was not meant to be.